# Is there a way to import a database from Visual Studio to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to login on a database in Microsoft SQL Server that was created in Microsoft Visual Studio. I can't for the life of me work this one out.

When I launch both programs, Microsoft SQL Server has a database in it which was used for testing - and Microsoft Visual Studio has the same database plus another one called 'SAMdeskEntities' which was created in VS.

[image: (Attached Image)]

I'm trying to load up 'SAMdeskEntities' in Microsoft SQL Server but cannot work out how to do so.

Comment: See that "database" in Management Studio, that's not a database it's an instance of SQL Server.  If you expand the `+` then you will see many other objects under it, one of which will be a list of databases.  To see your other database you would need to first logon to the instance of SQL Server that is hosting it, which looks like it might have a logical name of `SAMdesk`.

Comment: This solved it for me. Many thanks!